# How to make a command with a line number instead of normal syntax

Tags: javascript

So what if instead of doing:

```
if (apple == red) {
alert ("red")
```

i would do:

```
The apple is red

if (line 1 == red) {
alert ("red")
```

so my question is if it is possible to make a statement with a line number instead of actual syntax in Javascript.

Comment: no - it isnt [possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Have you ever programmed before?

Comment: "lines" don't *mean* anything in the hungry winking alligator world of javascript - `{};`

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What is the meaning of  `The apple is red` in this case, as part of a JavaScript program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing but two solutions:

## `.split()`

```
var lines = myText.split('\n'); //Splits lines
if (lines[0].toLowerCase().indexOf('red') > -1) { // Checks if 0th (1st line) contains 'red'
    alert("Red!");
}
```

## Read text after `is`

```
var noun = 'apple',
    lines = myText.split('\n');

if (lines[0].match(new RegExp(noun+'\s*is\s*\b(\w+?)\b', 'i'))[1] === 'red') {
   alert('Red!');
}
```

## Basic answer

You can split a text into lines using: `.split('\n')`. Example

```
var lines = multiLineTextString.split('\n');
```

Now in JavaScript, `lines` will start at zero so the first line will be `0` the second `1`, etc. So to select it:

```
line[0] === 'red'
```

This will be true if the text of the first line is `red`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about a string (`text`) you have separated by a new line character.

```
var lines = text.split('\n');
if(lines.length) {
    if(lines[0].match(/red/)) {
        alert("The first line is red");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa6e4xyk/

Comment: Great answer - but i don't think that's what the OP means.